# ASP.net Web form and Fancybox wont load on page load with a predifined image

Tags: jquery, asp.net, fancybox, webforms

I have a photo-galley which i show using fancybox, It works fine. i need to add additional functionality so that user can share photograph link by email with their friends and so on.

I am using asp.net web form c# along with master-page design for my main photogallery and i load gallery with fancybox using iframe as from my main Photogallery.aspx page.

It works fine now i want user to open the same link shared my email in fancy box on the main page Photogallery.aspx.

I use java script to check if query-string "emailImgID" is present then i trigger a hidden link to load the fancybox but it doesn't work but below is the latest version of code.  I have tried different thing but it doesn't seems to work..

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("a.iiframe").fancybox({
                'scrolling': 'no',
                'width': 830,
                'height': 650,
                'autoScale': false,
                'transitionIn': 'none',
                'transitionOut': 'none',
                'type': 'iframe'
            });



            $.extend({
                getUrlVars: function () {
                    var vars = [], hash;
                    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
                    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
                        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
                        vars.push(hash[0]);
                        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
                    }
                    return vars;
                },
                getUrlVar: function (name) {
                    return $.getUrlVars()[name];
                }
            });

            // i use this part to trigger link event so that it can load fancy box rather it shows only loading icon and doesnt load fancybox
            var urlVars = $.getUrlVars();
            if (urlVars['emailImgID'] != "") {
                $("#MainContent_hidden_link").fancybox().trigger('click');
            }

    });


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working Script:** I managed code to work with minor change to the script, It works fine now

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a.iiframe").fancybox({
            'scrolling': 'no',
            'width': 830,
            'height': 650,
            'autoScale': false,
            'transitionIn': 'none',
            'transitionOut': 'none',
            'type': 'iframe'
        });

        $.extend({
            getUrlVars: function () {
                var vars = [], hash;
                var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
                for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
                    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
                    vars.push(hash[0]);
                    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
                }
                return vars;
            },
            getUrlVar: function (name) {
                return $.getUrlVars()[name];
            }
        });
        var urlVars = $.getUrlVars();
        if (urlVars['emailImgID'] != null) {
            $("#<%= hidden_link.ClientID %>").trigger('click');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the querystring part of the url use `location.search`.

Change `getUrlVars` method to.

```
           getUrlVars: function () {
                var vars = [], hash;
                if(winddow.location.search){
                   var hashes = winddow.location.search.split('&');
                   for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
                       hash = hashes[i].split('=');
                       vars.push(hash[0]);
                       vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
                   }
                   return vars;
                }
            },
```

And check like this

```
        var urlVars = $.getUrlVars();
        if (urlVars['emailImgID']) {
            $("#MainContent_hidden_link").fancybox().trigger('click');
        }
```

Comment: It doestnt work, even the second part of code is not even fired. While in my code i am able to get into the if statement only problem is that i am not able to trigger the statement $("#MainContent_hidden_link").fancybox().trigger('click');
I tried other version line $("#MainContent_hidden_link").trigger('click');
and $("#MainContent_hidden_link").click();. nothing works